# Navigation height and padding

Tags: css, menu, background, navigation

I made a photoshop menu but I have problems converting it in CSS. The problem is that I have sometimes multilines sometine not! If someone can please help !

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
.training_nav {
  float: right;
}
.training_nav li {
  float: left;
}
.training_nav li.finances {
  background: url(img/finances_icon.png) center 35px no-repeat;
}
.training_nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.training_nav li a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NeqYa/1/

Many thanks !

Comment: Post the html of the menu as well.

Comment: It would also help to know what is being produced with your current CSS, could you please post an image or link to a jsFiddle?

Comment: Hey guys, here's the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NeqYa/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the css property `display:table-cell` really helps soothe your `vertical-align` issues. Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NeqYa/3/

Here's the CSS that made it work:

```
.training_nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #818181;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great ! But is there a way to move up the text when they are 2 lines like in my picture? To be centered with one line elements? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yeah sorry I made a mistake writing the SCSS file ! Thanks a lot Tim !

Comment: Can you please help me to achieve this with padding instead of fixed width? Of course I need 2 lines for big menu ! Thanks tim

Comment: It's not really possible to do while keeping sizes uniform. Your best bet would be percentage-based widths that change based on media query break points.